# logstash how to print the line and the full path in filter using grok or other method using s3 plugin

Tags: configuration, logstash, logstash-grok

I have grok expretion which looks like this :
the backet path is :

```
mylogs/b222/foo/32/*.logs
mylogs/b222/foo/33/*.logs
mylogs/b233/foo11/33/*.logs
```

and I have this grok excretion :

```
  grok {
            match => {
                "path" => "/mylogs/(?<version>[^/]+)/(?<project>[^/]+)/(?<projid>[^/]+)/" 
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure it captures the path structure fully

1. How can I debug what this grok is doing ?
   can I set prints?  to know if this regexp captureing and what in each group ?
   see
2. How can I print the line of log that the grok working on?

Answer (score 1):

2 options for this kind of issue :

- [Grokdebug](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) could be really usefull for you. It's a really easy online solution to test your grok expression.
- You could use [tag_on_failure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-tag_on_failure) and put a specific value that could be use as filter after for example to print on output the line that be doesn't match with the grok expression or to display this line in your elasticsearch/kibana stack.